# Searching with Panda based on specific categorization in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Dears,
I have a csv file with below content, There are several Teams with members and Team, Now I want to select a captain and the another person who is the replace of Captian in an NBA Basketball team.

Different team exists, so I categorized them to TEAMA, TEAMB,TEAMC.

```
SiteCode          Name    Type      NO
TEAMA       Al Horford      A       20
TEAMA       Tiago Splitter  B       19
TEAMA       Walter Tavares  C       18
TEAMA       Kris Humphries  D       17
TEAMA       Paul Millsap    E       16
TEAMB       Mike Muscala    A       20
TEAMB       Mike Scott      B       20
TEAMB       Dennis Schroder C       18
TEAMC       Jeff Teague     A       20
TEAMC       Kent Bazemore   B       19
```

1. If Type=A Captian is A, If B exists A will be Captian of B and If Any other members exist B will be the Captian of any other member:
   I should add No of Captian and ReplaceCaptian to other columns, I don't know how to search based on team and find the NO of Captian and put it in CaptianNo fields.
   (I think I should go ahead and solve this by adding a for loop and search based on team.)

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\P.csv")
    df["Captian"] = ["A" if x=="A" or x=="B" else "B" for x in df["Type"]]
    df["CaptianNO"] = ["A" if x=="A" or x=="B" else "A" for x in df["NO"]]
    df["ReplaceCaptain"] = ["A" if x=="A" else x for x in df["Type"]]
    df["ReplaceCaptainNO"] = ["A" if x=="A" else x for x in df["NO"]]
    print(df)
    df.head(3)
    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Captian.csv')
```

Actual Result of code which CatianNO is A and not the NO value it's relative Captian .

```
ID  SiteCode    Name        Type    NO  Captian CaptianNO   ReplaceCaptain  ReplaceCaptainNO
0   TEAMA   Al Horford      A       20     A        A                A                20
1   TEAMA   Tiago Splitter  B       19     A        A                B                19
2   TEAMA   Walter Tavares  C       18     B        A                C                18
3   TEAMA   Kris Humphries  D       17     B        A                D                17
4   TEAMA   Paul Millsap    E       16     B        A                E                16
5   TEAMB   Mike Muscala    A       20     A        A                A                20
6   TEAMB   Mike Scott      B       19     A        A                B                19
7   TEAMB   Dennis Schroder C       18     B        A                C                18
8   TEAMA   Jeff Teague     A       20     A        A                A                20
9   TEAMA   Kent Bazemore   B       19     A        A                B                19
```

Expected Result:

```
ID  SiteCode    Name       Type NO  Captian CaptianNO   ReplaceCaptain  ReplaceCaptainNO
0   TEAMA   Al Horford      A   20      A       20              A               20
1   TEAMA   Tiago Splitter  B   19      A       20              B               19
2   TEAMA   Walter Tavares  C   18      B       19              C               18
3   TEAMA   Kris Humphries  D   17      B       19              D               17
4   TEAMA   Paul Millsap    E   16      B       19              E               16
5   TEAMB   Mike Muscala    A   20      A       20              A               20
6   TEAMB   Mike Scott      B   19      A       20              B               20
7   TEAMB   Dennis Schroder C   18      B       19              C               18
8   TEAMA   Jeff Teague     A   20      A       20              A               20
9   TEAMA   Kent Bazemore   B   19      A       20              B               19
```

Comment: Is `ReplaceCaptain` correct? It is same column like `Type` ? Similar for `ReplaceCaptainNO` ?

Comment: Yes, It is fine.

Comment: Ok, then super. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For column `CaptianNO` use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df["Captian"] = np.where(df["Type"].isin(['A','B']), "A", "B")
df = df.join(df.set_index(['SiteCode','Type'])['NO'].rename('CaptianNO'),
             on=['SiteCode','Captian'])
```

Alternative:

```
d = {'NO': 'CaptianNO', 'Type':'Captian'}
df = df.merge(df[['SiteCode','Type','NO']].rename(columns=d), 
              on=['SiteCode','Captian'], how='left')
```

---

```
df["ReplaceCaptain"] = df["Type"]
df["ReplaceCaptainNO"] = df["NO"]

print (df)
  SiteCode             Name Type  NO Captian  CaptianNO ReplaceCaptain  \
0    TEAMA       Al Horford    A  20       A         20              A   
1    TEAMA   Tiago Splitter    B  19       A         20              B   
2    TEAMA   Walter Tavares    C  18       B         19              C   
3    TEAMA   Kris Humphries    D  17       B         19              D   
4    TEAMA     Paul Millsap    E  16       B         19              E   
5    TEAMB     Mike Muscala    A  20       A         20              A   
6    TEAMB       Mike Scott    B  19       A         20              B   
7    TEAMB  Dennis Schroder    C  18       B         19              C   
8    TEAMC      Jeff Teague    A  20       A         20              A   
9    TEAMC    Kent Bazemore    B  19       A         20              B   

   ReplaceCaptainNO  
0                20  
1                19  
2                18  
3                17  
4                16  
5                20  
6                19  
7                18  
8                20  
9                19
```

Comment: This is what I exactly looking for. completely I understood what to do. Many Thanks for time, energy.

Comment: Oh, just one problem. I have duplicated values. I have 18 rows, I must have 9 rows.

Comment: @SaraDaniel - It means there are duplciated values in `['SiteCode','Type']` columns? It is expected?